# The task factory "CodeTaskFactory" could not be loaded... visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Ok, I have found several similar issues, but none of them match (or fix) this.

Most of the fixes I have found refer to solutions that are being built in a version of VS that they were not created with, or some such. That does not apply to me, and their fixes do not appear to be possible

THis error started for me immediately after I tried adding GeckoFX from Nuget in a VS2015 solution with a crapload of projects in it. Only the project I tried to add it to is "broken" now. The others build fine.

The exact error is:

```
The task factory "CodeTaskFactory" could not be loaded from the assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v14.0.dll". Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v14.0.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.    Admin Application
```

That file does not exist. Now I understand from reading other peoples issues that this is usually fixed by changing the pattern of the build path inside one of the package files. My problem is I can find no reference at all to a dynamically built path that seems to fit. The closest path I can find

```
<UsingTask TaskName="DownloadNuGet" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">
```

That is in the nuget.targets file in the root of the solution, but as you can see the path is not the path that is "missing", and its not a dynamically modified path. So I have no idea where this issue is happening.

Can anyone give me a kick in the right direction? Ive got 3 hours on this already with no progress :/

Comment: ok, stranger and stranger. In the application's csproj file I noticed a change from ToolsVersion "4.0" to "12.0" ... not 14.0, but a change nonetheless, and since I dont know when that was last updated (I have not checked in that file in a long time), I changed it back to test... and while that did not fix the entire issue, now I can build using Build --> Build Solution, and no errors... and then I can start in debug mode because no build is needed. But if I just start debug without building the solution first, it errors out with the same error. Very strange!!